# CSS works with IDs but not with classes

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a project in WebStorm, and it appears that the CSS I'm trying to apply to parts of the project works when it's connected to an ID, but not when it's a class. Here's my current HTML in basic format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="firstJS.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="header" class="pageHeader">
        <h1>at the top</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>
    <div id="welcomeBox" class="main">
        <div id="welcome" class="headerOne">Welcome!</div>
        <div id="here">
            <div>here's some cool words <a class="boxLink" href="https://twitter.com">Contact</a> for help!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="firstLinks" class="main">
            <div class="headerOne">LINKS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#mainPage{
    background: lightgrey;
}
.pageHeader{
    font-size: 30px;
    background: goldenrod;
}  
.main{
    border: solid thick darkgoldenrod;
    background: goldenrod;
    border-radius: 15px;
} 
#welcomeBox{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
    left: 12%;
}
.headerOne{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}   
#welcome{
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}  
#here{
    position: relative;
    left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.boxLink{
    color: saddlebrown;
}
```

If I change the `pageHeader` and `boxLink` classes to IDs, the CSS does what I want it to do on the page (the `main` and `headerOne` classes seem to work perfectly fine as classes for whatever reason). But at the moment, the font size in `pageHeader` is the only thing I can change while they're classes that I can actually see changed on the page.

At an earlier point I also had a `<ul>` inside the `firstLinks` div, where each `<li>` in that list would have an `<a>` link in it that take someone to another page of the site (I didn't include those pages in this code at the moment). Those `<a>` links were supposed to use the `boxLink` class, but the formatting didn't carry over for those either.

Is there a workaround for this? Is there a way for me to make it a general class and have it apply to whatever element I want instead of hyper-specifying it to a specific `<div>`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Try with `#mainPage .pageHeader {...}` you have a CSS specificity problem here.

Comment: @Arkellys the thing is, I'm planning to have more pages to this project and I want to have the same formatting for the page header on every single page. I want to know if there's a way for me to make it so that I don't have to make new CSS for each page every time I want to have a page header. As I'm sure you know, HTML doesn't like duplicate IDs, so I would have to do it with a class.

Comment: If your pages are separated then you can use the same id `#pageHeader` for every page. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using in Your project the jQuery Mobile Framework, which is a mixed CSS-JavaScript Framework. What does this means? In a mixed CSS/JS Framework You will have some CSS Classes declared in a CSS Stylesheet and over that layer, at run-time. some other HTML fragments will be created by the Frameworkand and injected into the existing DOM. At run-time, the CSS classes of the Framework, which have been defined into the CSS Stylesheet, are applied to these new parts of the HTML page.

Take for example the JQM Header:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>at the top</h1>
</div>
```

If the JQM Framework has been referenced in the `head` and instanced, after page load it will parse Your HTML and enhance Your existing Tags with the corresponding Framework Classes. Toolbar (`header`) is one of the simplest enhancement. For instance, JQM Lists or Checkboxes/RadioButtons are enhanced in a more sophisticated way.

Each Tag which has the custom `data-role="header"` attribute will be enhanced as follows:

```
<div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit" role="banner">
    <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Page Title</h1>
</div>
```

Now, what if You need to change the default Framework styles with some of Yours?

This is a very common requirement. For this task, the Chrome or Firefox Inspectors are Your best friends. Just look at the hierarchy of styles definition. You will find out that some styles which have more specificity or are declared by using `!important` overrides some of the previously defined styles.

Note how Your custom `background-color` style defined inside Your custom `pageHeader` class of Your custom `style.css` file has been override by the JQM property defined by the Framework inside the `.ui-page-theme-a .ui-bar-inherit` classes of the `jquery-mobile-1.4.5.css` file:

[image]

Sorry for this boring explanation, now to the point. Obviously You don't know exactly which styles have been applied at page load and moreover, which styles are also applied dynamically at run-time. You *need* to explore the elements. The hierarchy goes from bottom to the top. You will easily find out what's happen in Your page.

This is the reason because Your custom `font-size` is working well but Your custom `background-color`isn't.

To get Your custom style applied, You can use either specificity over the JQM header classes, or `!important` for the `background-color` property:

```
.ui-header.pageHeader{
  font-size: 30px;
  background: goldenrod;
}  


.pageHeader{
  font-size: 30px;
  background: goldenrod !important;
}
```

Both will lead to the same result, it is just a matter of preference depending from Your needs and what You are trying to achieve. Here are some references:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

...just forgotten to mention that You can also override the JQM style directly:

```
.ui-header{
  font-size: 30px;
  background: goldenrod !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems your code is fine, kindly try the below Code if it works, then it seems to problem with your external stylesheet.
Kindly let me know if you face the same problem,
Also i have changed the JS files to Bottom.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <title>title</title>
<style>
 #mainPage{
    background: lightgrey;
}
.pageHeader{
    font-size: 30px;
    background: goldenrod;
}  
.main{
    border: solid thick darkgoldenrod;
    background: goldenrod;
    border-radius: 15px;
} 
#welcomeBox{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
    left: 12%;
}
.headerOne{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}   
#welcome{
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}  
#here{
    position: relative;
    left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.boxLink{
    color: saddlebrown;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="header" class="pageHeader">
        <h1>at the top</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>
    <div id="welcomeBox" class="main">
        <div id="welcome" class="headerOne">Welcome!</div>
        <div id="here">
            <div>here's some cool words <a class="boxLink" href="https://twitter.com">Contact</a> for help!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="firstLinks" class="main">
            <div class="headerOne">LINKS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="firstJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay @scally Kindly give me a minute to find an appropriate reason. Thank You

Comment: @scally Kindly validate your CSS Code through a Validator i am Pasting Link http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input   And Let me know if your CSS Seems fine with No Error then we will move on to our next point. I am also checking other reasons. Thank You